# How is switching frequency related to baud rate?

Tags: frequency, datasheet

Within [the datasheet of AM26LV32IDR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26lv32.pdf?ts=1620650581637), it is advertised that "Switching frequency is up to 32MHz", but there is no baud rate specified.

[image]

If we consider `t_rising` and `t_falling`, we can calculate that a square-like wave can be obtained at `1 / (4*5ns) = 50MHz`:

[image]

Moreover, the test setup had been run at 10MHz:

[image]

So where does the `32 MHz` come from? <s>How can I calculate the maximum frequency (=`kbps`) of input data signal?</s> What would be the maximum frequency of input 50%-duty-clock signal?

Answer (score 3):

That rate is how fast the device can receive data that has been encoded.

For example if you use biphase mark encoding, a stream of one bits would have double the frequency of zero bits, and for standard Manchester coding the bit rate is half of the frequency.

But for example UART transmissions, the frequency of signal can be half of bit rate, if you send alternating stream of ones and zeroes.

Comment: I should have been more clear about my protocol, yes. I meant an SPI-like protocol, where one channel sends a 50% duty square wave as the clock and the other channel transmits data on falling edges of clock. This would mean that the clock frequency is baud rate, right?

Comment: If your SPI clock is 32 MHz 50% duty square wave, the SPI data bit can change at maximum of each clock, so data has half frequency of clock rate or 16 MHz. The SPI still has one bit per clock or 32 Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

The transition time of 5 ns is a **typical** value, so it is not guaranteed and the maximum value may be **much higher**. In any event, there is no reason to assume that the minimum high and low times would also be 5 ns. So, that specification has no real value if you are interested in worst-case data rate.

Unfortunately, the datasheet is not very clear about what they mean by "switching rates up to 32 MHz", and they don't tell us how that value is measured. It sounds like you would need to contact the manufacturer for more information.

Comment: Yes, those 5ns long high and low states were just an example, totally made up by me. I couldn't think of what they possibly mean. By the way, datasheet states a strict 5ns of falling and rising times (just the typical value, no min or max values specified), so I assume the variation comes from another parameter.

Answer (score -1):

If we assume your baud rate is bits per second, then that translates directly into Hz. So 32MHz is a baud rate of 32 million bits per second. Clearly way in excess of kbps.
how did they come up with 32MHz? I didn’t read the datasheet closely, but it is probably derived from package dissipation, load capacitance, process variation etc.

Comment: Baud rate does not translate into Hertz. The IC uses binary signalling. A 1 baud period contains 1 transition, a 1 Hz period contains 2 transitions. The rest is guesswork and not-knowing and it's all just a comment, not an Answer. Downvoting, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TonyM, harsh, but true. Maybe if it were manchester encoded???